# Перемножение строк

Tags: c#

Как правильно сделать перемножение `string[]` ?

Пробовал сделать из 3х условий `for`, запихивая в новый массив, но что то дико долго работает,а от ещё большего количества слов, вообще замирает.

Задача (как пример, на деле же будут слова):

3 массива `string` c 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

На выходе должно быть:

- 001
- 002
- 003
- 004
- и т.д.

**UPD:**  Добавил код проб

```
string[] spisok1 = new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
string[] spisok2 = new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
string[] spisok3 = new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

string[] resultat = new string[spisok1.Length * spisok2.Length *spisok3.Length];

int cifra = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < spisok1.Length; i++)
{
    for (int o = 0; o < spisok2.Length; o++)
    {
        for (int p = 0; p < spisok3.Length; p++)
        {
            resultat[cifra] = spisok1[i] + " " + spisok2[o] + " " + spisok3[p];
            cifra++;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < resultat.Length; i++)
{
    textBox1.AppendText(resultat[i] + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Или вы предлагаете код за вас писать? Покажите что пробовали и что не получается

Comment: @tym32167 всё получается, 3 разных варианта пробовал, но все они одинаково медленно работали и все снёс, так как даже онлайн решения в 10ки раз быстрее работали, но сейчас напишу снова, если уж прям так оно надо.

Comment: @tym32167 добавил код

Comment: 1. Зачем вам 3 одинаковых списка? Вы можете использовать один список, и 3 цикла по нему ходить. 
2. Для конкатенации строк используйте [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)  - это будет быстрее, чем складывать строки

Comment: @tym32167 да вместо этих цифр будут разные слова - это просто пример.

Comment: Большую часть времени занимает вот это: `textBox1.AppendText`. Любые операции с GUI - медленные. Заносите результат в текстбокс **один** раз, предварительно получив его, например, в StringBuilder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, давайте начнем по порядку, вы записываете результат в массив, это отнимает время, вы работаете с циклом `for`, запись результата в массив, использование численных переменных, перезаписывание данных куда либо, т.е. построчное считывание результата по индексу.

Я не буду строить из себя крутого, но ваш код можно оптимизировать так, что он будет отнимать время на выполнение:

> ~Время затраченное на строку с результатом: 00:00:00.0003914

Сам код:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

string[] spisok = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

var sb = new StringBuilder();
stopwatch.Start();
foreach (string t2 in spisok)
{
    foreach (string t1 in spisok)
    {
        foreach (string t in spisok)
        {
            sb.Append($"{t2} {t1} {t}\n");
        }
    }
}
stopwatch.Stop();
TimeSpan ts = stopwatch.Elapsed;

Console.Write(sb.ToString());
sb.Clear();
Console.WriteLine($"Время затраченное на строку с результатом: {ts:T}");
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Возможно лучше будет использовать вместо `sb.Append(string.Format(...))` сразу `sb.AppendFormat(...)`. Должно работать чуть побыстрее

Comment: Ну да, примерно процентов на 30 быстрее работает.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуй через LINQ:

```
string[] str1 = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
string[] str2 = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
string[] str3 = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

var query =
    from s1 in str1
    from s2 in str2
    from s3 in str3
    select s1+" "+s2+" "+s3;


foreach (var n in query)
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Comment: У ТС проблема не с выборкой, а с использованием не тех средств вывода данных. Но сама выборка хороша, хотя и немного медленнее чем 3 цикла `foreach`

Comment: Ну здесь тоже можно воспользоваться `Aggregate` и собрать всё в один `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 2):

Переписал немного ваш код

```
string[] spisok = 
    new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };      

int cifra = 0;
var sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < spisok.Length; i++)
{
    for (int o = 0; o < spisok.Length; o++)
    {
        for (int p = 0; p < spisok.Length; p++)
        {               
            sb.Append(spisok[i]);
            sb.Append(" ");
            sb.Append(spisok[o]);
            sb.Append(" ");
            sb.Append(spisok[p]);
            sb.AppendLine();
            cifra++;
        }
    }
}

textBox1.AppendText(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: вместо этих цифр будут разные слова из textBox - это просто пример.

Comment: @Vipz ну адаптируйте мой код как вам надо, я просто показал вам, как ваш код заставить работать быстрей.

Comment: Чуть быстрее, но не пойму , как можно перемножить значительно быстрее ? Онлайн решения в поиске "перемножение списков слов" делают это мгновенно, в моих же случаях на C# это вечность , если чуть больше слов в каждом массиве по 25 например:(

Comment: @Vipz Какие онлайн решения? На чем они написаны?